# powercfg: If the Current DC Power Setting Index is 1 does that mean DC USB devices still have selective sleep enabled?

Tags: windows-10, usb, sleep, power

There is a USB device on my Windows 10 (Build 21H1) that falls asleep but should not.

When I look at the Power Profile in the GUI it's set to `Disabled`.

I ran `powercfg /Q <uuid-of-active-power-profile>` on my computer, and got the following output:

```
...

>   Subgroup GUID: 2b737411-1930-4202-8d78-b2b3bba308a3  (USB settings)
>     Power Setting GUID: 48e6b7a6-50f5-4782-a5d4-53bb8f07e226  (USB selective suspend setting)
        Possible Setting Index: 000
        Possible Setting Friendly Name: Disabled
        Possible Setting Index: 001
        Possible Setting Friendly Name: Enabled
      Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
      Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
...
```

If `Possible Setting Index: 001` means `Enabled`, and `Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001`, does this mean that for this profile, is `USB selective suspend` is still enabled on all USB DC devices?

Comment: `001` and `0x00000001` are the same value.  "only the power supply is AC) sleep is still enabled?" - According to the output you provided DC Power Setting is enabled not AC Power Supply Setting. You don't really specify what you are trying to achieve by disabling/enabling this setting, so it's difficult, to submit a question (since I assume you made a typo in the only question you asked).

Comment: @Ramhound Does this setting mean that Selective Sleep is still enabled for USB DC devices?

Comment: Your question made no mention of Selective Sleep.

Comment: @Ramhound My bad; `USB selective suspend`

Comment: My first comment addresses that part of your question